# Layouts doesn't work in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, layout, button

i'm having a problem with layouts in Qt. I'm trying to compile this code, with 2 horizontal layouts and a vertical main layout. Each horizontal layout have 3 buttons and both horizontal layout are incorporated in the vertical layout. But after i compile this code, i can only see a small window with just the "Exit" button.

```
firstline = new QHBoxLayout(this);
secondline = new QHBoxLayout(this);

layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

eat = new QPushButton("Eat", this);
drink = new QPushButton("Drink", this);
smoke = new QPushButton("Smoke", this);

save = new QPushButton("Save", this);
load = new QPushButton("Load", this);
exit = new QPushButton("Exit", this);

firstline->addWidget(eat);
firstline->addWidget(drink);
firstline->addWidget(smoke);

secondline->addWidget(save);
secondline->addWidget(load);
secondline->addWidget(exit);

layout->addLayout(firstline);
layout->addLayout(secondline);

setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: Remember there's [`QGridLayout`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QGridLayout.html) that probably is simpler to use in this case.

Comment: I know, but layouts just doens't work. I rewrited this code using QGridLayout and is just the same result. The problem must be mine or i'm missing something in code.

Answer (score 4):

You are already setting the layout for your dialog through these statements...

```
 firstline = new QHBoxLayout(this);
 secondline = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

So call their constructors without specifying their parent widget.

```
firstline = new QHBoxLayout();
secondline = new QHBoxLayout();
```

This would display your layout as you are expecting.

Comment: @Mat The parentheses in the new calls have a very stinky difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/620402/256138. Best to just include them.

Comment: @rubenvb: I disagree. Theses are clearly non-PODs and all the Qt documentation is written without the parens.

Comment: It still doesn't work properly. Same result after letting the constructor blank.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any layout added via Qt IDE.It worked fine on my system

Comment: Oh, i figured the problem and solved it. I was using QMainWindow as the window widget instead of using QWidget. Thank you for helping me.